# How to add Hyper Link in Excel file in iOS Using XlsxReaderWriter

Tags: ios, swift, excel, hyperlink

I used XlsxReaderWriter library to generate Excel File. Everything is working perfectly but when I set attributed string with "link" attribute it is not working. Link is not applying to text.

Github Link : 
https://github.com/renebigot/XlsxReaderWriter

It is working fine with below code :

```
let documentPath:String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "demo1", ofType: "xlsx")!
let spreadsheet: BRAOfficeDocumentPackage = BRAOfficeDocumentPackage.open(documentPath)
let fooWorkSheet: BRAWorksheet = spreadsheet.workbook.worksheets[0] as! BRAWorksheet
let title = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Title", attributes: [
                                                .font: FONT_BOLD(30),
                                                .foregroundColor: UIColor.red
                                                ])
fooWorkSheet.cell(forCellReference: "Title", shouldCreate: true)?.setAttributedStringValue(title)
```

**But It is not working with below code :**

```
let documentPath:String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "demo1", ofType: "xlsx")!
let spreadsheet: BRAOfficeDocumentPackage = BRAOfficeDocumentPackage.open(documentPath)
let fooWorkSheet: BRAWorksheet = spreadsheet.workbook.worksheets[0] as! BRAWorksheet
let title = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Title", attributes: [
                            .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
                            .link: "http://www.google.com"
                        ])
fooWorkSheet.cell(forCellReference: "Title", shouldCreate: true)?.setAttributedStringValue(title)
```

So someone please help me !!!

Comment: When you say it isn't working, what happens and what do you expect to happen? Are there any error messages?

Comment: When I changed font, font-size and color it is working fine with the attributed string but When I apply ".link" attribute nothing happen in excel sheet which I get. There is no error message but link is not applying to text.